# run R code from Linux to windows

Tags: r, linux, windows

My collaborator ran R code on a Linux operating system. But I only have windows now. I am only trying to run this R code which is known to work on a Linux system.

I need to read a large csv files with more than 400,000 rows. My computer cannot handle this large file so that I only read the first 10,000 rows. Then a simple left join function did not work with this truncated file. The syntax of this left join appears correct.

```
data_tag <- left_join(data, tags, by = "app_id")
```

> Error: `by` can't contain join column `app_id` which is missing from
>   LHS.

I have checked many times that `app_id` is in both files.

Is that possible that the file changed slightly when switching from a Linux to Windows? Or somehow, the truncated file can not be read correctly into R?

Any help is  highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure both files were correctly read into R?  Maybe there is a slight name change in the columns.  Compare `names(data)` with `names(type)` to verify the column names.

Comment: r u using the same csv in both linux & windows? the line ending requirements on both os are diff.

Comment: Yes. I am pretty sure that both files were read into R. There is no name change in the columns.  The first file data.csv is quite large. Although I only read the first 10,000 rows, it has more than 4500 columns. There are parsing issues with this data.csv file. I am using the same csv in both Linux & windows. I know that the line ending requirements are different. But I don't know how to deal with it.